# replace loop variable in system shell command of ipython

Tags: python, for-loop, ipython, magic-function

I would like to iterate through a list (of sample names) and repeat the same command for each sample using the system shell command of ipython ("!"). I have done this previously with no problem but keep getting a SyntaxError under this specific code. If you know what is wrong please let me know - thank you!

Here is the sample code (in reality there are more samples):

```
samples = ["ERR007200", "ERR007204", "ERR007208"]
def remove_ambMap():
    !samtools view -q 20 -b home/pathToFile/{samp}.realn.bam | samtools sort - {samp}
for samp in samples:
    remove_ambMap()
```

Note that samtools is a program that is in the $PATH and that if I perform the command specifying the path of the file it works - sorry this will not be reproducible as you need to have the program installed and these are massive genomic files - I am hoping someone might be able to spot what is wrong!

Comment: Can you post the SyntaxError?   The same code (replacing samtools with various bash built-ins) works for me.

Comment: Sure @jedwards: !samtools view -q 20 -b /home/tmsmith/data/expEvo/RGA/RGAbams/Bais/{samp}.realn.bam | samtools sort - {samp}
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I've had it work for other programs in the past, perhaps it is just something specific to this program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of task you'd use to use the `subprocess` module; the
easiest would be to use the `call` method with `shell=True`:

```
from subprocess import call

def remove_ambMap(samp):
    call('samtools view -q 20 -b home/pathToFile/{samp}.realn.bam '
         '| samtools sort - {samp}'.format(samp=samp), shell=True)

for samp in samples:
    remove_ambMap(samp)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if taking out the ipython dependencies would solve the problem and it appears to do so.